# How to check if <InputB /> has a value after a value for <InputA /> has been selected?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, input, google-places-api, google-places-autocomplete

I have the two following input components:

```
function Inputs() {
  return (      
    <div>
      <GooglePlacesAutocomplete
        onSelect={(data) => getPointA(data)}
        placeholder="Enter place or address for Point A"
      />

      <GooglePlacesAutocomplete
        onSelect={(data) => getPointB(data)}
        placeholder="Enter place or address for Point B"
        idPrefix="pointB"
      />
    </div>
  )
}
```

When I select a value from the first GooglePlacesAutocomplete component, I want to check if the second GooglePlacesAutocomplete component has a value. How can I do this? Here is a link to the component I'm using: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-google-places-autocomplete

Thanks!

Comment: Store your selected data in you parent component (Here 'Inputs'), this way you'll be able to check if the second GooglePlacesAutoComplete has a value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store the state of your selected values in you `Inputs` component so you have access to the selected values:

```
function Inputs() {
  const [placeA, setPlaceA] = useState('');
  const [placeB, setPlaceB] = useState('');
  const getPointA = (data) => {
    setPlaceA(data)
  }
  const getPointB = (data) => {
    setPlaceB(data)
  }
  return (      
    <div>
      <GooglePlacesAutocomplete
        onSelect={(data) => getPointA(data)}
        placeholder="Enter place or address for Point A"
      />

      <GooglePlacesAutocomplete
        onSelect={(data) => getPointB(data)}
        placeholder="Enter place or address for Point B"
        idPrefix="pointB"
      />
    </div>
  )
}
```